# scaling_cur_freq is low (lower than scaling_min_freq) when battery is low

Tags: amd, cpu-frequency

I have a chinese noname laptop with AMD Ryzen 3 3250U. Here is [lshw](https://pastebin.com/xJyyFmJc), [lscpu](https://pastebin.com/xcZNYDhi), [cpupower frequency-info](https://pastebin.com/F8rSXMqR)

When the battery is less than 25%, the processor frequency is about 400000 kHZ (according to /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq), but scaling_min_freq is 1400000.
I  set /sys/module/processor/parameters/ignore_ppc to 1, but it doesn't help.

What can I try to prevent this slowdown? Can it be hardcoded in BIOS? There are no any power management settings in BIOS of this laptop. Other user of this model reported that there is some problem in Windows.

I use Ubuntu 22.10, kernel 5.19.0-29-generic, no additional power management tools (e.g. tlp) installed.